# How can I post a string to an ASP.NET Core action method from Angular?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, post, request

How can I post a string to an ASP.NET Core action method from Angular?

Here is what I am trying:

**client side**:

```
this.http.post(
    "http://foo/bar/baz", 
    "foo",
    { responseType: "text" }
).pipe(
    map(res => res)
);
```

**server side**:

```
[Route("bar")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : BaseApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("baz")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStr(string str)
    {
        return GenerateResponseMessage(str);
    }
}
```

Whenever I am getting to the `return GenerateResponseMessage(str);` line using a breakpoint, the `str` is null. While I am expecting the `str` to be equal the `"foo"`. What am I missing here?

Help me, please. I always thought that it is very easy to `post` or `get` anything with the help of Angular and ASP.NET Core, but it seems that the evil is in details, because I can not figure out the issue for too long.

I need to `post` the string. I am aware of the `get` option, but my specific case requires posting the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/bar")]
[ApiController]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
[HttpPost("baz")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody]string str)
```

this way you can solve

Answer (score 1):

FromBody should do the trick:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStr([FromBody] string str)
```